# Recursive file copy and rename on the Vista command line

Tags: command-line, windows-vista, recursion, copy, for-loop

I'm trying to recurse through my music directory and copy every file called folder.jpg to a file in the same directory called cover.jpg.

I've tried variations of suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210413/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows) such as this:

```
for /r %i in (folder.jpg) do copy %i cover.jpg
```

Resulting in "The system cannot find the file specified."

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
for /r %i in (folder.jpg) do copy "%i" "%~picover.jpg"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %I in (`dir /b /s ^| findstr folder.jpg`) do copy "%I" "%~pIcover.jpg"
```

Decoder Ring:

```
usebackq :: run the command in the backquotes and use the output as the input for the loop
delims== :: use the equal sign as a delimeter. Really you could use any character that isn't valid in a file name
dir /b /s :: do a recursive directory listing only outputting the bare file names
^| :: ^ escapes the pipe character, the pipe - well pipes the output from the first command to the second
findstr :: searches the input for matching lines, and only outputs them
%~pI :: the tilde p instructs the variable expansion to only output the path rather than full file name + path. Note, this includes a trailing \
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's pretty intense command line action. It did the trick perfectly thanks. Also the Decoder Ring was great, especially the part about %~pI. I found that

    for /r %i in (folder.jpg) do copy "%i" "%~picover.jpg"

also worked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have any files in your music folder called folder.jpg so it fails right?

I tried this in mymusic folder with a dummy file called folder.jpg and it copied it normally. ;)

Edit:

Kishi is right, you are missing the double quotes on the second %i

Comment: Actually you were right at one stage :P I had previously recursively renamed all folder.jpg files to cover.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing double-quotes on the copy command.

The %i variable will be holding the full-path to the file -- which may contain spaces.
Try using:

```
for /r %i in (folder.jpg) do copy "%i" cover.jpg
```

Comment: Yeah I did miss the quotes actually, thanks. The next problem was that it would always copy to the directory from where I ran the command, eg. e:\Music

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell must replace CMD. It is inevitable and righteous. And it's my job to help it along...

```
gci -r . folder.jpg | % { copy $_.FullName ([IO.Path]::Combine( $_.Directory.FullName, "cover.jpg" )) }
```

Comment: SO's formatting of PowerShell code blocks doesn't work very well, as the syntax isn't very C-like. So I usually use <PRE> for PowerShell.  In this case, it decided that the two '_' should make a span italic, even in <PRE>.  So I made the compromise and switched it to a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use xcopy with the /s flag...

EDIT:
My bad - didn't read the question properly. Xcopy with /s will help when just copying the files to a fixed destination.